# FREETDS Dateformat issues

Tags: c, sql-server, freetds, sqsh

Below SQL statement

```
SELECT getdate()
go
```

When I run from SQL Server management studio it gives

```
"Jul 27 2016 22:00:00.860"
```

When I run the same from sqsh it gives

```
"Jul 27 2016 10:00PM"
```

sqsh uses freetds to connect to SQL server from my linux box. I have a C program which uses freetds and it will work fine when date is retrieved in 24hour format.

I guess there are settings for freetds to get date in required format, can someone please suggest how to accomplish that by freetds settings.

Comment: I dont know the answer, but for your question not sure what of those two you need to fix.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I just did on my ubuntu linux box:

1. Type this command at the bash shell: `locale` My result (shortened): `LANG=en_US`
2. Copy locales.conf file to the config directory: `sudo cp /usr/share/doc/freetds-common/examples/locales.conf /etc/freetds/`
3. open the `/etc/freetds/locales.conf` file in an editor
4. comment out the old date format defined in the locales.conf file (I've used ";" as a comment char), copy the line
5. Define a date format that you need in the corresponding section of the locales.conf file

   `[en_US]`

   `;date format = %b %e %Y %I:%M:%S:%z%p`

   `date format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`
6. restart your web server process

Now I get from `sqsh`:

```
SELECT getdate();
: 2016-08-01 11:37:45
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but unfortunately I don't have access to /etc/freetds/, its restricted for my developer login. Any alternative to place the file in <<myowndir>>/freetds/locales.conf and use this directory.

Comment: Add point 6.... an apache restart is required!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the default date format returned by FreeTDS is configured in the `locales.conf` file. See http://www.freetds.org/userguide/locales.htm for details.

Comment: hey, I set environment variable LOCALE = <<mypath>>/locales.conf and modified date format as per my need but still no luck.

Comment: Corrected link: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/locales.html (edit queue is full, please edit the question when possible and delete this comment)